# how to save the result of a t4 template on a different folder

Tags: t4

When i try to specify an absolute path for the generated files using

```
someTemplate.RenderToFile("c:\\tmp\\filename.ext");
```

I'm getting the following error

Error   263 Running transformation: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): There is already a file of the same name in this folder.

even though the folder is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitor,

Are you using Template.RenderToFile method from [T4Toolbox](http://www.codeplex.com/t4toolbox)? If yes, this method currently doesn't support saving files to a different folder. This has been on my to-do list for a while. What are you generating, anyway?

Comment: I built a template of the row data gateway (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/rowDataGateway.html) to use in simple asp.net webapps.

And everytime i change someting in the db schema and have to generate those classes I have to manually copy them to main project... which is kinda boring...

Answer (score 3):

This functionality was implemented in version 9.3 of T4 Toolbox: http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=25294